# How to make a program that allows the user to label what type of input is provided?

Tags: ruby

I have a program in Ruby that takes a phone number and is able to pull information from that number. It can tell me the area code, the root, and prefix of the number.

I now want to add another parameter where the user can input that this particular phone number is their cell, work number, etc.

For example:

```
MyContact1 = Info.new ('(555) 555-5555', :home)
=>(555) 555-5555 (home)

MyContact1.label
=>"home"

MyContact2. = Info.new (' 555-555-5555, "work")
=>(555) 555-5555 (work)
```

Here is my code:

```
class PhoneNumber

  def initialize (ph)
    @ph = ph
    @ph.insert(0, '(')
    @ph.insert(4, ')')
    @ph.insert(5, ' ')
    @ph.insert(9, "-")
  end
  def to_s
    @ph
  end
  def area_code
    @ph.slice(0..5)
  end
  def prefix
    @ph.slice(6..8)
  end
  def root
    @ph.slice(10..13)
  end
end
print "Please enter a phone number: "
puts a = PhoneNumber.new(gets.strip)
puts a.area_code
puts a.prefix
puts a.root
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: You need to try, then when that fails ask a specific question. Your code shows no evidence of trying to add the field, so it looks like you want us to write it for you. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages, along with "[mcve]" and “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)”.

Comment: In production code, or code that is designed to accept international numbers I'd recommend not blindly inserting information into a phone number. You're assuming a user didn't already put those in, and, if the number is not U.S.-based your formatting will be wrong. Instead you should strip on everything used for formatting, store the value, then later, if you need to present it to the user, reformat it appropriately for their region or country.

Comment: @theTinMan: is part of this comment canned? or do you type it from scratch each time? Is there a shortcut for the third link, like `[mcve]`?

Comment: Heh. I have snippets and combine as necessary. The last is just stored as a snippet and I copy/paste it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just extend your initialize method to accept more arguments:

```
class PhoneNumber

  attr_reader :label

  def initialize(ph, label)
    @ph = ph
    @label = label
    # ...
  end
  # ...
end
```

Now you can pass a number **and** a label, and you have a method defined to retrieve this label:

```
a = PhoneNumber.new('555-555-5555', :home)
#=> #<PhoneNumber:0x007fd7cb149fb0 @label=:home, @ph="(555) -55-5-5555">
[8] pry(main)> a.label
#=> :home
```